# How to select multiple layers in Photoshop CS6

Tags: select, photoshop, layer

I have PSD file with about thousand layers. And I have one selected shape area. And 0 layers are selected. Now my question is how to select only those layers that are in selected shapes. Layer is in selected shapes if part or all layer is in selected shape. Selected shape is non rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible with the ctrl - click. You can hold ctrl and then select layers you want to have selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a way to do this by shape area ,either a path or a selection, automatically that is not possible. (There might be a script or plug-in but not one I can think of off-hand.

**A possible workaround:**

If you select the move tool and check "Auto Select" and "Layer" in the options bar you can click an area of an image and Photoshop will    automatically select a layer that contains the content you clicked.

If you hold down the shift key you can select multiple layers (shift-clicking a layer you already selected deselects that layer.) If there is a layer behind another layer it will always select/deselect the front-most layer. To get around this right-click the area that contains both layers, a list of layers in order will appear and you can select the layer you want by name. *(see image)*

[image: Right-Click Layer Selection]

Using this method you should be able to capture all of the layers within a certain area by hand in a fairly efficient manner.

After you have all the layers you want selected you can either group them (which is the best method but doesn't work if you need to maintain their current layer order in relationship to all of the other layers in the document) or you can link them which will allow you to select or move them together in the future.

Not sure if this solves your problem, hope it helps.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Holding `Shift key` & select your multiple objects

Answer (score 0):

For Single selection:
Click Control(ctrl) button and select your layers.

For multiple selection:
Use Shift and then click your layers.